# How to convert website using webform to .net mvc core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, webforms, upgrade

Now i have website [TDMWATER](http://tdmwater.vn//)
Microsoft ASP.NET
4.0.30319

Some time it very slow , downtime , every one week i must rebuild source code and restart server to reslove this problem so i decided upgrade from webform .net framework . How to convert from webform 4.0 framework to mvc .net core by some tool and reuse old source code is the  best ?

convert website using webform to .net mvc core

Comment: There is no magic conversion tool. You may be able to convert a .NET Framework project to .NET Core, but not Web Forms to MVC. If you have separated the business logic and data access code from the presentation then those lower layers will only need to change target framework. Otherwise, you would need to do that separation first or else start from scratch.

Comment: It's slow because you're application pool is shut down due to inactivity, and then it has to start up from scratch. Set the idle timeout to zero so it never shuts down, or have some proces do a "ping" or a ""wget" on some page to keep the process alive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be considered from many aspects:

**1. Page**

You need to replace the original page with the appropriate html page.

**2. Background logic**

According to the website you posted, most of them belong to the standard CRUD interface. Design each entity first, and then use AbpHelper.Gui and AbpHelper.CLI to generate related codes and interfaces. The generated interface can basically be used, and what needs to be improved is to increase the query function and adjust the authority.
The DataTables.Net-based page generated by the ABP MVC/Razor Page template supports paging and sorting, but it does not support query by default, and needs to be added according to the actual situation. We can use the query function that comes with DataTables.Net to realize the query.

**3. Import of website data**

This part mainly includes product data and activation-related data. You can use an ADO library written by yourself for .Net Core to export the original data to Xml, and read the data from Xml in the new application for initialization.

**4. Product content page**

The content of the product was originally kept in the database, but now it is saved in the file. When the product page is loaded, the display is read from the file.

**5. Url relocation**

Including the Url for exchanging data with the outside world and the interface Url for ensuring SEO consistency. It can be realized by the ReWrite middleware of .Net Core.

**6. Deploy and run**

This needs to be determined according to your own situation. If you want your website to withstand more traffic, you still need a more powerful server.

**Of course, this is a huge project in itself and I am also very new to your website source code. So you need a professional team.**

Comment: i think i will resuse core linq and writing new everything